# nodejs https server doesn't respond

Tags: node.js, https

My https server is running but it doesn't handle requests:

```
const crypto = require('crypto'),
      fs = require("fs"),
      http = require("http");
var https = require('https');

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('C:\\dev\\apps\\OpenSSL-Win64\\batar\\azerty.pem');
var cert = fs.readFileSync('C:\\dev\\apps\\OpenSSL-Win64\\batar\\tg.pem');


var options = {
  key: privateKey,
  cert: cert
};

console.log( options );

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  console.log("handling request");
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

When I enter the server address localhost:8000, the browser loads for ages and will end up with an "empty response" error.

Here is the server output:

```
C:\>node dev\nouille\server.js
{ key: <Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 42 45 47 49 4e 20 52 53 41 20 50 52 49 56 41 54 45 20 4b 45 59 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a 4d 49 49 43 58 51 4
9 42 41 41 4b 42 67 51 44 56 61 4c 41 ...>,
  cert: <Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 42 45 47 49 4e 20 43 45 52 54 49 46 49 43 41 54 45 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a 4d 49 49 43 66 7a 43 43 41 65
67 43 43 51 43 63 66 52 6a 78 57 32 72 ...> }
```

Comment: just to be sure you did `https://localhost:8000` right ?

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't. Well, now that works ... Thanks !

Comment: happens to all of us sometime or other ;)

Comment: Is there a way to detect on the server-side that HTTP protocol was used and either close connection, or redirect? Because right now (Node vo.10) connection stays open until it times out.

Comment: @Pius It probably can be done on a lower level in the network stack. You would need to access the underlying tcp server, but I don't know if you can do that with node's https

Comment: @user568109: This, so much this. Hahah, that was my error! You clever badger, you!

Comment: I restarted server, and it worked. So weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly caused by not connecting over the `https:` protocol. With most browsers eliminating the "http(s)://" from the url, it's an easy mistake to make, especially on a dev box where the https server is configured on `https://localhost:8443`, or some other non-standard port.

So, check your protocol first before pulling out any more of your hair.

-- Thanks [@user568109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/568109/user568109) for the guidance!