# Node.js, handler callback isn't called

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https

Here is a simple code example:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("./ssl/key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./ssl/cert.pem")
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(443);
```

All requests to localhost:443 leads to **infinite pending**.

I run this example by: "sudo nodejs https.js"

No errors/warnings observed. Port 443 have a "Listening" state. https://www.dropbox.com/s/uchpbn0ifacmf4x/node.jpg?dl=0

Problem reproduced on my linux and windows machines.

I also tried node lib called "pem" with the same result.

`http` works fine in my environment.

Node version: 0.10.33

Could you please help my with problem investigation? May be I can activate more debug?

**UPDATE**: strace

```
{{EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}}, 1024, 119999) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {1989619, 754364596}) = 0
accept4(10, 0, NULL, SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 11
futex(0x7f577c0008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1418596391, 472239}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7f577c0008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1418596391, 472445}, NULL) = 0
accept4(10, 0, NULL, SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {1989619, 755788224}) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 11, {EPOLLIN, {u32=11, u64=11}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=11, u64=11}}}, 1024, 119999) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {1989619, 755916479}) = 0
read(11, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost"..., 65536) = 583
gettimeofday({1418596391, 472940}, NULL) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {1989619, 756589265}) = 0
futex(0x7f577c0008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=10, u64=10}}}, 1024, 119999) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {1989619, 758012624}) = 0
accept4(10, 0, NULL, SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 12
futex(0x7f577c0008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1418596391, 475378}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418596391, 475522}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418596391, 475798}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418596391, 475836}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418596391, 476235}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1418596391, 476272}, NULL) = 0
brk(0x12c0000)                          = 0x12c0000
brk(0x1300000)                          = 0x1300000
mmap(0x8138ef00000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x8138ef00000
mprotect(0x8138ef05000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x8138ef06000, 1019904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x8138ef06000
mprotect(0x8138efff000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
gettimeofday({1418596391, 478274}, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7f577c0008c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
gettimeofday({1418596391, 478657}, NULL) = 0
accept4(10, 0, NULL, SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {1989619, 762218983}) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 12, {EPOLLIN, {u32=12, u64=12}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, ^CProcess 15474 detached
```

**Update**: I use digitalocean droplet.
Ubuntu 14.04 x64 vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic (1221)
Linux r___t.ru 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: What distro and kernel are you testing with for Linux?

Comment: I use digitalocean droplet. Ubuntu 14.04 x64 vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic (1221), (Linux r___t.ru 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux). **Also** proplem exist on Windows 7 PC.

Answer (score 0):

Hhha...

The root cause of this proble is request to "**http**://localhost:443" instead of "http**s**://localhost".

Thanks to [nodejs https server doesn't respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278976/nodejs-https-server-doesnt-respond)